# Connect multiple wallets simultaneously to Dapp

Tags: wallets, dapps

Is it possible to have simultaneous connections to multiple wallets?

What I mean, to make it as clear as possible, is to connect a MetaMask wallet to my Dapp and to connect Trust wallet and say one more wallet example.